# SQL - Get number of rows WHERE "something = something" but not limited by LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I had a pretty hard time describing this problem in the title, but basically I need to be able to get the number of rows my SQL query returns from the WHERE clause but is not limited by the LIMIT clause.

Example:

I have a table consisting of 10 posts. They all have column "show" = "true".

I then write my query like this:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE show = 'true' LIMIT 5";
```

I now need to get a variable on how many posts would be returned, had the `LIMIT` not been there.

`$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);` does not work as it'll only tell me 5 because of the `LIMIT`. I somehow need to know that there's 10 posts with column "show" = "true", even though my query only returns 5 posts because of the `LIMIT`.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table WHERE show = 'true' LIMIT 5;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Another option is to issue two distinct queries, one to get the first five (as you have already), and another to get the total count:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE show = 'true' LIMIT 5;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE show = 'true';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()`:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*
from table t.*
where show = 'true'
limit 5;
```

Then:

```
select found_rows();
```

The documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).